# Enumeration in C

Tags: c, enums

```
enum {YES=1,No=0};
int main()
{
    int i;
    i=YES;
    printf("%d",i);
}
```

works well.

```
enum B{YES=1,NO=0};
int main()
{
    enum B i;
    i=YES;
    printf("%d", i);
}
```

also works well.

```
typedef enum {YES=1,NO=0} Boo;
int main()
{
    Boo i;
    i=YES;
    printf("%d", i);
}
```

works too.
Is there any difference? When is one of them preferred over another?

Comment: I don't see any difference between the second and third example? Also, sir sir: `int main( void )`...

Comment: Can you do `enum B i; i = 42;`?

Comment: sry i got copied it wrong! Now its ok

Comment: and what about that void?

Comment: you can, it is really kinda weird. Everything is possible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C, there is very little difference been a variable with an `enum` type and a regular `int`.  C allows implicit conversion from an `enum` value to an `int` as well as implicit conversion from an `int` to an `enum` value, so they are practically interchangeable.  The only practical difference that I know of is that using the enum type will more clearly express your intent that the values should only be one of the named values of the enumeration.

Note that this is in contrast to C++, where enum values can be implicitly converted to `int`, but not the other way around.

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically, there's a little catch in your 2nd and 3rd examples.

Unlike C++, standard C merely says that *each enumerated type shall be compatible with an integer type. The choice of type is implementation-defined.*

Therefore it is theoretically possible (though, of course, barely sensible and probable) that an implementation chooses an integer type which has a higher rank than that of `int`.

In such case, the `%d` format specifier may not correspond to the promoted type of `i`, which means undefined behavior.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between your first and second (and third) example is that you are defining `i` as two separate data types. One being an `int` and the other being an `enum B`.

There is no difference between the second and third example. Recall that the purpose of `typedef` is to assign different names to data types (and also declaring opaque structures... don't get on me about that).

Comment: Thx, it's just like if there were a fork and a spoon on the table, and you asked me whats the difference and i said, one is a fork the other a spoon!

Comment: @StefanStojkovski, if you can't realize that one is round and the other is pointy then I don't know what else to say. You could of easily of tested the difference on your own -- all I see are snippets of code, no assumptions or tests by you. That's not how SO works, we don't perform your analysis -- we correct your analysis or assure you that it's right. *When* you decide to make an assumption of your own and state it in your question then I will edit my answer with a less sarcastic one.

Comment: Look at the other answer from Vaughn Cato.